# Couldn't find boost folders in '/usr/include' and '/usr/local/include' when installed using "sudo dnf -y install boost"

Tags: c++, installation, boost, boost-graph

I am fairly new to Additional Libraries in CPP and was working on a server with **CentOS 8.5.2111** with **GCC 8.5.0 20210514**. I tried installing Boost Library to use **Boost Graphs** using the following commands -
`sudo dnf makecache --refresh`
`sudo dnf -y install boost`

I wrote a very basic CPP program to import the boost graph libraries -

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

and compiled the program using the following command -
`gcc network_task.cpp -o network`
but was met with the following error -

```
network_task.cpp:2:9: fatal error: boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include<boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I looked at other answers and they said to include the complete path of boost folder. First, I tried adding the boost as an argument while compiling -
`gcc -I boost network_task.cpp -o network`
but was met with the same error.

Then, I tried finding the folder for boost and the only path I could find was `/usr/share/licenses/boost-graph` which contained only the `LICENSE_1_0.txt` and nothing was present in the `/usr/include` and `/usr/local/include`.

Is there any other way I should install the boost library for graphs or is there any other folder where the required files are present? Also, help me with how to include the boost header file for the graphs and compile the program.

Comment: *'I looked at other answers and they said to include the complete path of boost folder'* Very bad advice. What this does is instead of finding out why your perfectly correct code is not working, you are now trying to work with incorrect code. Solve the actual problem, why the compiler can't find the headers.

Comment: I have no idea (not a Linux expert) but a successful installation of boost is going to leave hundreds, maybe thousands, of header file somewhere on your system. If you do not have that then I can only say that the boost installation failed, and that is the problem you should be investigating.

Comment: OK, a little google and my **suspicion** is that you have only installed boost documentation is that there is another package called boost-devel (maybe) that you need to install if you want to do development with boost, and maybe one called boost-thread as well. As I said I'm not Linux expert so please do your own research.

Comment: @john I was wondering the same aswell, but I was confused whether the header files are contained in `/usr/include`, `/usr/local/include` or somewhere else. If they can be present somewhere else, then I wanted to know where that could be. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Most linux distributions split their libraries into a binary package (everything in `/lib` and `/bin`) and a developer package with headers and other stuff you only need to compile your own code. See if you find a `boost-devel` package or something like that

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved.
Turns out, along with `boost`, I also had to install `boost-devel`. But, since the sudo commands were not under my priviledge, I had no control on what packages to install and what not.

`sudo dnf -y install boost-devel` did the trick.

Thanks [@Homer512](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17167312/homer512) for the advice -

> Most linux distributions split their libraries into a binary package (everything in `/lib` and `/bin`) and a developer package with headers and other stuff you only need to compile your own code. See if you find a `boost-devel` package or something like that

Also, to compile the program, `g++ network_task.cpp -o network` simply works.